# meaning of "reassuring herself with that terrible euphemism ‘home’"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm reading *The Versions of Us* by Laura Barnett. One character's husband is suffering from Parkinson's disease and:

> "She pictured herself leaving, handing his care over to a nurse of
>   whom they could expect no more than a distant, anonymous kindness;
>   leaving him in a hospital somewhere, reassuring herself with that
>   terrible euphemism ‘home’."

I don't understand what "reassuring herself with that terrible euphemism ‘home’ " means. The dictionary says that euphemism is "a mild, indirect, or vague term for one that is considered harsh, blunt, or offensive." But in this sentence, is "home" a mild term for hospital or what? Does this mean that she's trying to lie to herself that hospital can also be a home? Can anybody explain its meaning for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is struggling with placing her husband, the person she married and who's children she (possibly) bore, into **institutional care**.  After this is done, the new facility will become his **new home** from which he will **only leave once**.

The **terrible euphemism** used for the care facility is **home**.
A **euphemism** is using a word which is nice or good to describe something which is not.

> The melody in the air

when used to describe a foul smell is a euphemism.

> Nursing home
>   Care home

are euphemisms for institutional care.

She will tell her friends:

> I've found a new **home** for him
>   We've put him in a nice new **home**

still referring to where he lives with the same moniker as if life continued unchanged.  But she will know deep down that the facility is not as **warm** or **comforting** as their **real home** was.

However, the wife is trying to find comfort in calling the new institution **home**

A recent trend, due to the significant aging population, is **home care** or **home health care** where medical professional come to the patient's home rather than the patient moving into a care facility.

Answer (score 2):

In context, she's alluding to the compound noun phrase...

> [**nursing home**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nursing%20home) *- a place where people who are old or who are unable to take care of themselves can live and be taken care of*

The implication being that where the couple currently live is their...

> [**home**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/home) *- the place in which one's domestic affections are centered*

...but a commercially-run care establishment has no connection to "one's domestic affections".

Comment: By the way, I notice that the author, Laura Barnett, is from the UK; she may have been thinking of the phrase *care home* instead, but it works either way.

Comment: @stangdon: Feasibly. But even sticking to just the BrE corpus, Google NGrams supports my gut feel that [***care home*** is far less common than ***nursing home***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+care+home%2Ca+nursing+home&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20care%20home%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20nursing%20home%3B%2Cc0).